# Karate UI Automation 1

Tags: karate

How to match if the Toggle is enable or disabled in Karate?

I tried 2 things :

1. And match enabled('locator') == false
2. And match enabled('#eg01DisabledId') == false

Comment: sorry you need to be a little more clear. maybe this toggle is hard-core javascript, in which case only you can figure it out. or please edit your question to give an idea of the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Without the HTML it is hard to answer your question.

You could try clicking on the element using `mouse()`.

```
* mouse('#eg01DisabledId').click()
```